# Add content on click

Tags: vue.js

in my application i have a simple loop on `tr` element, to build a table:

```
<tr v-for="user in users"></tr>
```

Because i'm using an accordion, i will need two rows (the first row generated with `v-for` and another row that is the accordion):

```
<tr></tr> Generated with v-for
<tr></tr> Row for accordion
<tr></tr> Generated with v-for
<tr></tr> Row for accordion
```

So, `v-for` iterate the collection and for each row, i have another row (that is the accordion).

I would like build the "additional row" when the user click on the row generated via `v-for`.

So, how i can "attach" this row below the selected row ? I have think to use slot, but i'm a bit confused...

And, when the user click on another row... the previous attached row should be removed and the next one, will be attached on the selected.

In short, the same behavior of Bootstrap Accordion.
*I need this* because in this way i can load the accordion content "on demand".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping them both around a `<template>` element as such :

```
<template v-for="user in users">
  <tr></tr> Generated with v-for
  <tr></tr> Row for accordion
</template>
```

The `<template>` element will not be rendered.